# Armadillo+OpenBLAS slower than MATLAB?

Tags: c++, blas, armadillo

New to SO. I am test-driving Armadillo+OpenBLAS, and a simple Monte-Carlo geometric Brownian motion logic shows much longer runtime than MATLAB. I believe something must be wrong.

Environment:
Intel i-5 4 core,
8GB ram,
VS 2012 Express,
Armadillo 4.2,
OpenBLAS (official x64 binary) v0.2.9.rc2,

MATLAB takes 2 seconds for the same logic, but Armadillo+OB takes 12 seconds. I also noticed that the program is running on single thread, but I turned to OpenBLAS because I heard of its multi-core capability.

Thanks for any advice.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <ctime>

using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

int main()
{
clock_t start;
start = clock();
unsigned int R=100000;
vec Spre = 100*ones<vec> (R);
vec S = zeros<vec> (R);
double r = 0.03;
double Vol = 0.2;
double TTM = 5;
unsigned int T=260*TTM;
double dt = TTM/T;
for (unsigned int iT=0; iT<T; ++iT)
{
    S = Spre%exp((r-0.5*Vol*Vol)*dt + Vol*sqrt(dt)*randn(R));
    Spre = S;
}
cout << mean(S) << endl;
cout << (clock()-start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Comment: It looks like the loop doesn't end up calling any BLAS functions, so OpenBLAS is probably not the issue. I suspect that optimization and vectorization need to be explicitly enabled within your compiler. Armadillo is a template library, and as for all template libraries, optimization during compilation is an **absolute must**. Also bear in mind that the MS VS compiler is not known for robustness or generating fast code. Far better performance can be achieved by the GCC or [Intel C++ compiler](http://tinyurl.com/kkvsjdv). You can get GCC for Windows via the [minGW project](http://www.mingw.org).

Comment: Further updates: Seems to be the randn(R) that slows the entire logic down. Switched to zeros<vec>(R) then completed in less than 2 seconds. Switched to randn(R) then again 12 seconds... This is more likely the Armadillo problem rather than an OpenBLAS problem. Very frustrating...

Comment: @mtall switched to Eclipse+MinGW, now runs 52 seconds... really lost...

Comment: What are your compiler invocations? If you're running an unoptimized build things are bound to be slow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Key observation is that Armadillo exp() function is way slower than MATLAB.
Similar overhead is observed in log(), pow() and sqrt().

Comment: Armadillo ends up calling std::exp(), std::log(), etc, which means the speed issue is with the std:: functions (ie. from the standard C++ library). How these functions are implemented is dependent on each operating system and/or compiler. On Windows + VS this may not be that great.

Comment: Thanks @mtall. I switched to MinGW64 and ended up with the same disappointing performance. Should I try Linux+GCC?

Comment: Try using the `-ffast-math` option with gcc, which relaxes some of the strict safety guarantees. Often this speeds up programs. Otherwise you may want to look at using the [vdexp()](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/521788) function from Intel MKL, which can be [easily interfaced](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/11555/an-efficient-way-to-convert-between-mkl-and-armadillo-types) with Armadillo vectors and matrices. Matlab internally uses MKL, so you'll get the same performance as Matlab.

Answer (score 3):

First, the bottleneck is not exp(), though std::exp is slow. The problem is randn().

on my machine, randn() takes most of the time. And when I use MKL_VSL 's implementation of randn, the time cost dropped from 12s to 4s, comparable to matlab's 3s or so.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <armadillo>
#include <ctime>
#include "mkl_vml.h"
#include "mkl_vsl.h"
using namespace std;
using namespace arma;

#define SEED 0
#define BRNG VSL_BRNG_MCG31
#define METHOD 0
int main()
{
clock_t start;
VSLStreamStatePtr stream;
start = clock();
vslNewStream(&stream, BRNG, SEED);
unsigned int R=100000;
vec Spre = 100*ones<vec> (R);
vec S = zeros<vec> (R);
double r = 0.03;
double Vol = 0.2;
double TTM = 5;
unsigned int T=260*TTM;
double dt = TTM/T;
double tmp = sqrt(dt);
vec tmp2=100*zeros<vec>(R);
vec tmp3=100*zeros<vec>(R);
for (unsigned int iT=0; iT<T; ++iT)
{
    vdRngGaussian(METHOD,stream, R, tmp3.memptr(), 0, 1);
    tmp2 =(r - 0.5 * Vol * Vol) * dt + Vol * tmp * tmp3;
    vdExp(R, tmp2.memptr(), tmp3.memptr());
    S = Spre%tmp3;
    Spre = S;
}
cout << mean(S) << endl;
cout << (clock()-start) / (double) CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
vslDeleteStream(&stream);
//system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but it looks like you need to set the number of threads to use in OpenBLAS via the `OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS` environment variable.

Try something like:

```
set OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4
```

...on the command line before you run your program.  Substitute the number of cores in your system where I put "4" (some would say set it to twice the number of cores in your system--YMMV).

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I tried this: "C:\Release>set OPENBLAS_NUM_THREADS=4

C:\Release>TestOpenBLAS
116.44
12.434
Press any key to continue . . ." Did I understand your suggestion correctly? It still takes 12+ seconds, and still runs as a single thread.

Comment: @AndreasBVB: First, are you running from the IDE or from the command line?  It's probably best to just set the environment variable once & for all for your system (via System Properties->Advanced->Environment Variables on most Windows versions).  Then make sure you restart your IDE to get a fresh environment.  While you're at it, make sure you're building a "Release" build and not running via the debugger.  Then we'll see what kind of performance gap remains.

Comment: Thanks @Drew Hall . I set the system ev, rebooted and restarted VS2012. Compiled again under x64 Release, and still get the same thing. Now I doubt it is the way binaries are made. Let me test Intel MKL sometime, then I will have a better idea.

Comment: @AndreasBVB:  Are you running via the debugger, or clean?  You need to press the "run without debugging (shift-F5)" button if you're doing this from the VS IDE or the debugger will kill your performance.

Comment: I actually tried two ways: 1) Run w/o debug 2) Run from system command line. None of them helped. I have tested the same logic with ArrayFire GPU library, and it was very impressive, so now I tend to suspect that binaries are compiled as single thread... However 12-second runtime is still too long even for single thread. Thanks.

Comment: @AndreasBVB - check that optimization and vectorization are explicitly enabled in your compiler. Template libraries such as Armadillo require optimization.

Comment: @mtall Thanks for the input. I am kind of restricted to VS2012, so is there any setting I could try first? e.g. the optimization and vectorization settings you mentioned. Where are they in VS2012? Thanks. I found C++->Optimization->Full Optimization (\ox) but nothing else closer...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have Streaming SIMD Extensions enabled when you compile your code. In Visual Studio, check your project C/C++ compiler code generation options.